# Best windows based network monitoring software

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, monitoring

I want to know which is best windows based network monitoring tools mainly for monitoring network and control internet access.

I want to monitor the bandwidth of internet usage in each machine in network. websites accessed by each machine.

Are there any there is any opensource tools?

Answer (score 1):

I use Zenoss to monitor my windows and unix boxes.  The windows boxes are monitored though a combination of SNMP and WMI which doesn't require a agent on each of the system.

Here is a link to the zenoss community
http://community.zenoss.org/index.jspa

Here is a link to the WMI ZenPack(plugin)
http://community.zenoss.org/docs/DOC-3392

You can also join the IRC (Freenode #zenoss) for help.

Answer (score 0):

What logging facilities does your Internet router support? Some can give the stats you want if you run a [syslog server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog) app on your local computer. Here's a freebie:

http://www.solarwinds.com/products/freetools/kiwi_syslog_server/